# Playwright closed page when element not found

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

The second click below timed out becasue the element was not exist on the page. this error cause the 2nd iteration of the loop not work. I expected try-catch can catch such error but looks like this error closed the page.

Here are the code

```
  while (jsonData[row]['TAR_OPTY_ID'] !== '') {

    try {

      await page.goto(URL + 'customerRequest.action')

      await page.goto(URL+ "opportunity.action?customerId=" + jsonData[row]['TAR_CUST_REQ_ID_NBR'])

      await page.goto(URL+ "version.action?opId=" + jsonData[row]["TAR_OPTY_ID"] + "&objectAction=unspecified")

      await page.click('xpath = //span[contains(text(), "Rating Outputs")]')

      await page.click('xpath = //a[text() = "Get Formula Rating"]')

    } catch (error) {

      console.log('error is', error)

    } finally {

      row++

    }
  }
```

Here are the errors:
error is page.click: Page closed

=========================== logs ===========================

waiting for locator('xpath= //a[text() = "Get Formula Rating"]')

============================================================

```
at C:\Users\U455893\Desktop\playwright\tests\rate.spec.js:68:23 {
```

name: 'Error'

}

error is page.goto: Target page, context or browser has been closed

```
at C:\Users\U455893\Desktop\playwright\tests\rate.spec.js:64:23 {
```

name: 'Error'

}

error is page.goto: Target page, context or browser has been closed

```
at C:\Users\U455893\Desktop\playwright\tests\rate.spec.js:64:23 {
```

name: 'Error'

tried wait for selector but not work, still same error.